# RxJS from() method. Local variable name conflict

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Given the following code

```
getExchangeRates(source: string, target: string, from: string = "", to: string = "") {
  return this.exchangeRateDataService.getExchangeRates({ source, target, from, to })
    .pipe(
      map((response: HttpResponse<ExchangeRates>): ExchangeRates | undefined => {
          return response.body ? from(response.body) : of([]);
      })
    );
}


Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures.
```

My issue is that I can't use the rxjs from method, because the from variable creates a naming conflict. Is there any alias available for the rxjs from() method? Is there any other way to solve this issue? (Modifying the interface is not an option, I can't change 'from' to 'fromDate')

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't change the name of the variable you could use the `import as` syntax to change the name of the method:

`import { from as rxFrom } from 'rxjs';`

then use it:

`return response.body ? rxFrom(response.body) : of([]);`